# Git Merge & Conflicts 101

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I am puzzled by git (I've always used svn), my use case is as follows:

I change File1 on my local repository while my friend changes the same file on his. Both changes are useful. He commits and pushes. At this point I would like to open this file in a compare view, get his changes into my file and then commit and push the edited file (svn style).

Needles to say I can't do this in a proper way, I always end up resetting my local changes and adding them back. I am using Eclipse or SourceTree, I'd prefer not to use command line for such a task.

Can you suggest an approach to this scenario? How would the "git-way" be in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Conflict resolution itself is not much different between Git and Subversion.

But the crucial difference between the two is that in Git, each commit records the state of the whole repository; you can't "send" the changes in just one file or a directory to the server and make it create a synthetic commit *there.*  Since there's no "server" in Git model (what you perceive as a "server" is just another Git repository, not *essentially* different from yours or that of your fellow developer), all commits happen in someone's local repository, and merges are no exception.

So with Git you have two options when you want to reconcile your unpushed work with someone else's changes: merging and rebasing.  Both *must* result in a new state of the whole project which can be pushed to the shared repository.  I mean please take time to fully understand the part "Disaster 2: Merging Without Understanding" of ["Avoiding Git Disasters: A Gory Story"](http://randyfay.com/node/89) as it deals with a possible problem people with Subversion mindset instilled in their brains might unwillingly create for themselves.

Now it's the time to read a book on Git to learn how to merge and how to rebase.